# Derivative of $x^x$ using first principle

Tags: limits, derivatives

Find $f'(x)$ with $f(x)=x^x$ using first principle.

i.e. evaluate the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{(x+h)}^{x+h}-x^x}{h}$$

EDIT:
$x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ so we need to evaluate $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{{(x+h)}\ln{(x+h)}}-e^{x\ln x}}{h}$$

I know the answer is $x^x(\ln x+1)$ but how can one prove it using first principle?

Comment: What definition of $x^x$ are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by definition?

Comment: How do you compute $\pi^\pi$? In order to be able to find the derivative of a function, you need at the very least a precise definition of that fuction.

Comment: The expression is to be differentiated with respect to x. $\pi^\pi$ is a constant and can be found out.

Comment: I know. And I am asking what definition of the expression $x^x$ you are using? You surely are using *some* definition! **How** you find out the value of $\pi^\pi$?

Comment: $f(x)=x^x$ x is any real number if thats what you want. I find out the value of $\pi^\pi $ by raising 3.14159265358... to 3.14159265358... the same way i would raise 2 to the power 3 to get 8

Comment: Your function is defined only for rational values? One usually only computes derivatives of functions defined over open intervals.

Comment: Sorry, i meant real.

Comment: You still have not answered by question (and I am not being dense just for the pleesure of it: you **will not** be able to compute the derivative of the function unless you know the definition of the function!). What is the value of $\pi^\pi$?

Comment: Its 36.462159607

Comment: To raise $2$ to the power of $3$ you compute $2\cdot2\cdot 2$. How do you do this for $\pi^\pi$?

Comment: $\pi$ times isnt it

Comment: And **how** do you do that? How can you multiply $2$ by itself $\pi$ times?

Comment: The point being, you usually have to go well beyond "first principles" even to define $x^x$ for real $x$, much less differentiate it. Incidentally, $(-1)^{\pi}$ is not really defined--at least, not as a real number.

Comment: Ok, i searched and I don't know exactly what you mean by a definition. Do you want ordered pairs like (1,1) (2,4) (3,27) ?

Comment: $x^x$ is usually defined as $e^{x \log{x}}.$ Is this your definition?

Comment: @user80551 I think what MarianoSuárez-Alvarez is referring to when asking what is the value of $\pi^{\pi}$, is that it is not quite straightforward how this can be done. How can you multiply $\pi$ by itself $\pi$ times? Try to figure out if you can do this by hand. The answer is probably no, unless you know the definition of $x^x$.

Comment: The definition that perhaps works best is to define $$\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1}{3!} x^3 + \frac{1}{4!} x^4 + \cdots$$ (which must be proved to actually make sense), and then define $\ln$ to be the inverse function of $\exp$ (which must also be proved to make sense), and then define $$a^x = \exp(x \ln a.)$$ As a special case, you get that $$x^x = \exp(x \ln x).$$ Since you've already got this expression from the definition, there's no real advantage in trying to pretend you don't have it when differentiating.

Comment: An additional note why going back to "first principles" is not very helpful here: the proof that $\exp$ has an inverse function typically involves using the chain rule and finding the derivatives of $\exp$ and $\ln$ as side effects. So if you know what $x^x$ really means, then you already have the tools to differentiate it without going back to "first principles."

Comment: @user80551 What about do you suppose $2^{1/2}$ means. "Multiplying $2$ by itself a half of a time"? (so we have a similar problem with $\pi$. Well we know at least formally that $[2^{1/2}]^2=2$, so that $2^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}$ (it could have been chosen to be negetive, but it wasn't since $2^n$ is always positive and we want to keep that). But now what do we do about $2^{\pi}$. The problem is $\pi$ cannot be written as a ratio of two integers, so we need a new way to say what things like $x^y$ are.

Comment: I think Mariano used here in a rather interesting and educative way the maieutics method Socrates made so famous, according to Plato. Bottom line, some times one discovers one doesn't know even what one's asking about.

Comment: I think it is clear now to @user80551 that he should use $e^{x\ln{x}}$ as the definition for $x^x$. I suggest that people now try to answer the actual question, as the answer to that is not at all straightforward yet.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I do not understand the motivation behind your questions here, which sounded to me as a sort of interrogation. The OP is clearly not aware of some of the more advanced notions you are trying to describe. What good does it make to mention "the derivatives of functions over open intervals?" Why not directly ask "Is $e^{x\log x}$ your definition, would you check your book?," or sth like that?

Comment: @LordSoth, I think we're dealing here with students at college/undergraduate level at least. One could, should and would expect from them to be way more careful about their work in mathematics. Conceeded, most, or many, of us were more or less the same back then, but most or many of us had to learn, sometimes the hard way, to be careful. When a student asks a question I expect he understands at least the very basic terms around his question, and in this case I think Mariano's questions made it clear the OP didn't know that. Hopefully we all, and the OP mainly, learned from this.

Comment: No effort.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Dear @Mariano, there is exactly one way to extend the function $a^b$ from $\mathbb R_{>0}\times\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R_{>0}\times\mathbb R$ — and in practice that's all one need to know about the definition of $x^x$ — so I don't really see the point of your questions.

Comment: ...oh, and of course there are much more natural ways to obtain such an extension beside strange hack "let's just define $x^y$ as $\exp(y\ln x)$"

Comment: @GrigoryM I assume the point of the questions is that to find the derivative of $f$, at the very least we first need to know what $f$ is. As you say, there are several possible definitions. A proof from first principles would need to state which one we are adopting, and work from there. The OP didn't even seem aware that the definition of $f$ could be problematic (that "there is exactly one way" is besides the point).

Comment: @GrigoryM, I know. That provides one possible definition. What is not clear is that *that* was what the OP had in mind. I hoped it would be obvious that what I had in mind was precisely the fact that the OP (and not you or me) did not, in fact, have *any* definition at all in mind, thereby rendering impossible what he had set out to do. It would be very instructive if you could provide a computation of the derivative of our function starting from the definition you mentioned!

Comment: If you don't define the function at pi you obviously cannot compute its derivative there. I imagine you did not mean what you wrote.

Comment: I do know that $x^x=e^{x\ln {x}}$ I just didn't know that that's what you wanted. I'll change that in the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}=y
\iff x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac yn\right)^n
\iff x=e^y
\iff y=\log(x)
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-(x+h)^x+(x+h)^x-x^x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^h-1}{h}
+x^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(1+\frac hx\right)^x-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^h-1}{h}
+x^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{\large\frac xhh}-1}{h}\\[12pt]
&=x^x\log(x)+x^x\cdot\log(e)\\[16pt]
&=x^x\log(x)+x^x
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

To calculate the desired limit, one first has to know what is the meaning of the expression $x^x$. For some type of numbers, we can assume that we know how to calculate it, for example, $2^2=2\cdot2=4$.

On the other hand, what is $\pi^\pi$? Is it the product of $\pi$ by $\pi$, $\pi$ times? So we need a definition for the expression $x^x$. As @AlexP suggested in the comments, $x^x$ can be defined by $e^{x\log{x}}$.

Let's analyze this definition. The first thing to note is that to understand the definition, you have to know how to calculate the exponential of a real number, how to calculate the log of a real number and how to calculate the product of two real numbers. If we suppose that you know how to do all of this, then you know how to calculate $x^x$. Note that $x^x$ is defined only for $x>0$ (can you say why?).

Now, let's try to calculate the desired limit by using this definition.

\begin{eqnarray}
 \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h} &=& \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+h)\log{(x+h)}}-e^{x\log{x}}}{h}      \nonumber \\
   &=& \lim_{h\to 0}e^{x\log{x}}\frac{e^{(x+h)\log{(x+h)}-x\log{x}}-1}{h} \nonumber \\
   &=& \tag{1}\lim_{h\to 0}e^{x\log{x}}\frac{e^{x\log{(1+h/x)}+h\log{(x+h)}}-1}{h}
\end{eqnarray}

By using the definition of $e$ given by @Charles in the comments, we have that $$\tag{2}e^{x\log{(1+h/x)}+h\log{(x+h)}}-1=x\log{(1+h/x)}+h\log{(x+h)} \\+\frac{1}{2!}(x\log{(1+h/x)}+h\log{(x+h)})^2+...$$

Now, you can check that (for the first one try to use some fundamental limit)

$$\tag{3}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x\log{(1+h/x)}}{h^{1/n}} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
 x &\mbox{ if $n=1$} \\
  0 &\mbox{ if $n>1$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

and

$$\tag{4}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h\log{(x+h)}}{h^{1/n}} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
 \log{x} &\mbox{ if $n=1$} \\
  0 &\mbox{ if $n>1$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

By combining $(1)-(4)$ we conclude that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}=x^x(\log{x}+1)$$

Remark: How to justify the interchange of limits, i.e. if $f(h)=x\log{(1+h/x)}+h\log{(x+h)}$, how to justify $$\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{n\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}$$

First note that ($n\leq m$)

\begin{eqnarray}
 \left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}\right| &=& \left|\sum_{k=n}^m\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}\right|     \nonumber \\
   &\leq&\tag{5} \sum_{k=n}^m\frac{|f(h)|^k}{k!} \end{eqnarray}

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that $|f(h)|=\eta<1$ (note that this choice of $\delta$ depends on $x$, however $x$ is fixed) . It follow from $(5)$

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}\right|\leq\sum_{k=n}^m\frac{\eta^k}{k!}$$

From the last inequality and from the fact that $|f(h)|\to 0$ if $h\to 0$, we conclude that there exist $\overline{h}$ such that for all $0<h<\overline{h}$, the sum $\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{f(h)^k}{k!}\right|$ does not depends on $h$, i.e. the sum converges uniformly to $0$ as $h\to 0$. This implies that we can in fact interchange the limits.

Comment: This doesn't work as written. You are exchanging an infinite sum (effectively, a limit), and the limit as $h\to0$. In general, these two operations do not commute.

Comment: In this case it commutes, so I dont see any problem to do this. @AndresCaicedo

Comment: Tomás, this being mathematics and all, we actually justify our claims. This is a proof from first principles, right? You cannot just use as a black box what could perhaps be the trickiest or most technical part of the argument. (Well, of course you *can*, since you did. But assuming that you actually want to answer the OP's question...)

Comment: The point is that to make it work you have to explain *why* they commute.

Comment: You are right @AndresCaicedo, let me work on it.

Comment: What do you think now @AndresCaicedo?

Comment: Better, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome @AndresCaicedo, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer given by robjon, was alright, but there was one small mistake which I could not edit (MSE didn't allowed me, due to some lack of privilege), so the correct version is as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-(x+h)^x+(x+h)^x-x^x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^h-1}{h}
+x^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(1+\frac hx\right)^x-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^h-1}{h}
+x^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{\large\frac xhh}-1}{h}\\[12pt]
&=x^x\log(x)+x^x\cdot\log(e)\\[16pt]
&=x^x\log(x)+x^x
\end{align}
$$