# First Principles of differentiation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone show me how to differentiate $$y=x^x$$ by using first principles? I've been thinking this for so long but also couldn't solve.

Comment: What are "first principles"?

Comment: @EclipseSun: presumably, starting from the limit-based definition of the derivative...

Comment: @EclipseSun $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}$

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433135/derivative-of-xx-using-first-principle)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^x = \frac{d}{dx}e^{x\log x} = e^{x\log x}\frac{d}{dx}(x\log x) = x^x(\log x+1).$$

As an alternative, we can use the fact that for positive differentiable functions
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\,f(x) = f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log f(x)\right) $$
(prove it by considering limits or just the properties of the differential operator) holds, hence it is enough to find:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\log x\right).$$

Comment: I mean by first principles.

Comment: But this method doesn't use the "first principles". That's, the definition of the derivative using limits (I suppose).

Comment: @Mathxx: sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "first principles". Update incoming.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}$

Comment: @Mathxx: ok. Apply that to prove my second line, then my third one.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices (see Jack's answer) to find $\frac{d}{dx}x\ln(x)$

Now,

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x + h)\ln(x+h) - x\ln(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h(\ln(x) + \ln(\frac{h}{x} + 1)) + x\ln(\frac{h}{x} + 1)}{h}$$

$$ = \ln(x) + x\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\ln(h + x) - \ln(x)}{h} = \ln(x) + x\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \ln(x) + \frac{x}{x} = 1 + \ln(x)$$

Comment: How your $\ln (x) $is come?

Comment: @Mathxx: Note that "it suffices to find..." and that $\ln (x)$ is another expression for $\log (x)$.

Comment: I didn't want to write in details for two reasons: I'm lazy, and you should at least do something on your own.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{{h}\to{0}}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{{h}\to{0}}\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-(x+h)^x+(x+h)^x-x^x}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{{h}\to{0}}\frac{(x+h)^x\left[(x+h)^h-1\right]}{h}+\lim_{{h}\to{0}}\frac{(x+h)^x-x^x}{h}$$

$$=x^x\ln\left({x}\right)+\lim_{{h}\to{0}}\frac{((x+h)-x)\left[x^{x-1}+x^{x-2}\cdot x+...+x\cdot x^{x-2}+x^{x-1}\right]}{h}$$

Comment: Looks like some $h$'s got lost in that last line...